# ASP .NET MVC - Cannot nest foreach loops in view to display lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a website using ASP.NET MVC and I would like to display a list of objects that I retrieve from the database and another list for each object that was retrieved.

Here is my model:

```
public class JournalViewModel
{
    public JournalViewModel()
    {
        Issues = new List<Issue>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required, DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    public byte[] Content { get; set; }

    [Required, ValidateFile]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required, DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string IssueDescription { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string IssueTitle { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int IssueNumber { get; set; }

    public int IssueId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var userId = (int)_membershipService.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

    List<Journal> allJournals = _journalRepository.GetAllJournals(userId);
    var journals = Mapper.Map<List<Journal>, List<JournalViewModel>>(allJournals);
    return View(journals);
}
```

And my view:

```
@model List<Journals.Model.JournalViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section Style
{
    <style type="text/css">
        .table {
            table-layout: fixed;
        }

            .table td {
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow: hidden;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
            }
    </style>
}

<h2>Publisher - List of Journals</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@if (Model.Count == 0)
{
    <div>  Click @Html.ActionLink("here", "Create") to publish your first Journal.</div>
}
else
{

    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>File</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink(item.FileName, "GetFile", new { Id = item.Id }, new { target = "_blank" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var issue in item.Issues)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => issue.IssueTitle)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

This view used to work fine until I added this code:

```
@foreach (var issue in item.Issues)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(i => issue.IssueTitle)
        </td>
     </tr>
}
```

And now it has stopped working. What I am doing wrong?

Also, is there a way to retrieve an error message from this view?

Comment: What does "stopped working" mean?  Also, `JournalViewModel` has properties `IssueTitle, IssueNumber, IssueId` but also a list of `Issue`; why are those three properties there when they look like they should be properties of `Issue`?

Comment: What does your `Issue` class look like?  `IssueTitle` looks like it is property of `JournalViewModel`, not `Issue`

Comment: Hi, yes @PaulAbbott these properties should be a part of the Issue class, however I added them there tempoarily, so that I could make some tests. They will be removed.

Comment: When you compile your app and run it have you received the parser error "Unexpected "foreach" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "foreach" with "@"" ?

Comment: No, I haven't received this error and in fact I didn't receive any error at all. I am just shown to a blank page. By the way this is what I mean by it is not working anymore.

Comment: Try to remove `@` before a nested `foreach` cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@` before the nested `foreach` cycle. You have to also review your code and figure out the place where standard exception was suppressed. It can be either `customErrors` section configuration in `web.config` or `Application_Error` method in the `Global.asax.cs` file. When standard exceptions are not suppressed you can see the error page which allows you to understand what is the issue.

Comment: The exceptions were supressed in Global.asax.cs. Threre was a `Server.ClearError()` command in it.

Answer (score -1):

I have removed the `@` before the nested `foreach` as @Alexey Andrushkevich suggested and my page is working now.

Note: I was not being able to get any errors, because someone else had added this "great" error handling code in Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the exception object.
    Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

    if (exc.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
    {
        if (exc.Message.Contains("Maximum request length exceeded."))
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Error/RequestLengthExceeded"));
    }

    Server.ClearError();
}
```

Thanks to this, no error messages from the web pages were surfacing.